# Including constansts in strings

Tags: php, constants

Is there a shorter way of including PHP constant in a string? For example, instead of:

```
define("MYCONST","this");
echo "hello, my const is set to: " . MYCONST . ", and that is that.";
```

For example, I recently learned about the `{}` tags when including an array in a string, meaning you didn't have to escape out.  Is there a similar way to do that with constants, so that I dont have to escape out of the string everytime to include them?

i.e.

`echo "hello, my const is set to: {MYCONST}, and that is that.";`

..But this doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: If you don't like the default way, nothing prevents you from creating a function or a regular expression that will parse the given string and replace values with values from constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unfortunately you’ve got to concatenate the string if you’re wanting to use a constant within it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a constant this way. You need to add the string with it. Else, there is another way:

#### Try this:

```
define("MYCONST","this");
echo "hello, my const is set to: " , MYCONST , ", and that is that.";
```

#### Output:

```
hello, my const is set to: this, and that is that.
```

#### Demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/t63-1zx

Answer (score 0):

It will not work `{}` converts value as variable.